# Let $a,b,c\in \Bbb Z$. If $ab = c^2$, $(a,b)=1$, prove that $a$ and $b$ are both square.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $a,b,c\in \Bbb Z$. If $ab = c^2$, $(a,b)=1$, prove that $a$ and $b$ are both square.
Does anyone have any hints as to how I might go about solving this?

I tried using the fact that there exists $x, y\in \Bbb Z$ s.t. $ax + by = 1$, then multiplying by $c^2$, but I'm lost at that point.

Also I know $c|ab \implies c|a$ or $c|b$, but I don't really know how to prove that $a$ and $b$ are both square

Comment: There is one exception to this and that is $0\cdot (-1)=0^2$ which does not imply $-1$ being a square. This is typically avoided by assuming that $a,b>0$ or just non-zero.

Answer (score 3):

Think about prime factorization of $a$,$b$ and $c$. Use the Fundamental Theorem of Number Theory (Unique Factorization Theorem). I think this is easier than going via Bezout's lemma. Here is a way by which you can use Bezout's lemma and avoid prime factorization. First prove $(u^2,v^2)=(u,v)^2$. This can be proved by basic divisibility and Bezout's lemma. Then try to use this to solve the original problem.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply! I will try the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic in the morning, with fresh eyes! This problem is frustrating me greatly

Answer (score 1):

Using unique factorization, suppose for a prime $p$ that $p\mid ab$, so that $p\mid c^2$.

Then, using what you say in your last line, $p\mid c$, whence $p^2\mid c^2$. Therefore, ...

Comment: ahhhhh thank you! However, where would I need to use the gcd of a and b being equal to 1 here?

Comment: If $p\mid ab$, then by coprimality of $a$ and $b$, we know that $p$ divides exactly one of $a$ or $b$, so that $p^2$ divides exactly one of $a$ or $b$. This way we don't get any funny business with $p^2\mid ab$ but each of $a,b$ being divisible by an odd $p$-power.

Comment: So, I know that there exists a prime P such that p|ab. Thus, as ab = c^2, p|c^2. 

As p|c^2, p|c, therefore p^2|c^2.

As p^2|c^2, p^2|a or p^2|b. therefore a = xp^2 or b = yp^2, but I'm lost as to how I infer then that a and b are squares.

my apologies for the poor formatting, I don't know any technical writing languages. 

Also, my apologies for my ignorance. Number theory is a challenge for me, sadly :(

Comment: Say $a=xp^2$. If $p\mid x$, then as $(x,b)=1$ and $xb=(ab/p)^2$, we can repeat the same argument to get that $p^2\mid x$. We can repeat this process until we get $a=r\cdot p^{2n}$ for some positive integer $n$ with $(r,p)=1$. Repeating this with every prime dividing $a$ gives us (by unique factorization) that $a=p_1^{2n_1}\cdots p_k^{2n_k}$ for primes $p_1,\ldots,p_k$ and positive integers $n_1,\ldots,n_k$.

Comment: Thank you so much, Neth! While I don't quite understand everything you said, i am very frustrated with this problem and am going to try and look at it in the morning with fresh eyes. 

I seriously appreciate the help!